# Tomcat profiler to diagnose problems only evident on production site

Tags: tomcat, java

I'm working on a Struts site on a Windows server implementing new features and fixes to the JSPs, Actions, Servlets, underlyings JARs, pretty much most of it. Everything was going smoothly until a JAR update that'd been happy through testing caused the landing page to slow WAY down (10+ seconds to load).

What's puzzling is no other page is effected, the same page on my local dev server isn't effected, and most confusingly the same page on the test site that runs on the same Tomcat instance with a near mirror configuration, where the new classes and such were tested and then introduced from, isn't effected.  This blow to performance only occurs in the production site.

I've combed through the code and there's nothing happening on that page (JSP and associated Action) that doesn't also happen on other pages of this site where there is no slowdown. There are no exceptions showing up in the logs and loading the page doesn't have any perceptible impact in Performance Monitor. And I've totally restarted the Tomcat service like a whole bunch.

My instinct now is to profile it to find out what it's waiting on but Java VisualVM seems to think it can't run against JRE so I'm trying to figure out how to diagnose this problem.  My Google-fu is failing me so far.

Tl'dr; what tools are available for diagnosing performance issues in live Tomcat sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer enabling JMX in tomcat and profile using VisualVM. Here's info on how to enable JMX for profile https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890431/profile-tomcat-application-with-visualvm

Comment: Thanks.  I was running into this problem where VisualVM's default settings point at the JRE instead of the JDK and incorrectly interpretted that as an indication I was heading in the wrong direction. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24044069/visualvm-running-jre#24044137

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you'd use a profiler for this. There are several available.

My personal choice would be [YourKit Java Profiler](https://www.yourkit.com/) but keep in mind that is mainly because they give free licenses to open source developers so it is the one I am most familiar / comfortable with.